# adjust variable in query string

Tags: php, oop, http, variables, http-post

in my API access file, I have following code

```
//operation was successful get the token from the reponse.
$challengeToken = $r->result->token;
    // to this point, we have got the token 

$userAccessKey = 'jkdijakjiejkdj25';    
//generate key
$generatedKey = md5($challengeToken.$userAccessKey);
```

and I am using http_request2 class for sending post data, by declaring

```
$loginrequest = new HTTP_Request2('http://vijayholdings.com/admin/webservice.php?operation=login&username=admin&accessKey=('.$generatedKey.')', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
```

can somebody tell me How i can include $generatedKey in URL that is given as an Argument to the class?

FOR NOW

```
$loginrequest = new HTTP_Request2('http://vijayholdings.com/admin/webservice.php?operation=login&username=admin&accessKey=$generatedKey', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
```

I have tried this too, but at failure...

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use double quotes `" "` for the parser to pickup `"$variables"`.

Comment: 'http://vijayholdings.com/admin/webservice.php?operation=login&username=admin&accessKey="$generatedKey"'

I have tried this, but no success

Comment: No, `$loginrequest = new HTTP_Request2("http://vijayholdings.com/admin/webservice.php?operation=login&username=admin&accessKey=$generatedKey", HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);`

Comment: although variable got a different color in notepad++, but still not working

Comment: It works fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pGSGRw - you really should read a PHP tutorial....

Comment: thanks....then there might be some other error, if you dont mind, can you tell me how to add post parameters separately in http_request2 method post?